# PDF hyperlinks fail to open linked files on my computer

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, adobe-acrobat, hyperlink

I tried searching for an answer but did not get any. I am trying to export a Word document into a PDF. The word document has tables in which there are links to other files that are saved on my system. These hyperlinks work well and open files when used from the Word file itself. But, when I click a hyperlink in the generated PDF, the browser window opens and an error is thrown. I am not sure if this has anything to do with relative or absolute links. I just want the hyper links in the generated PDF to open these files, instead of opening a browser window. I do not have Adobe Acrobat, I just export the PDF directly from a word file.

Answer (score 0):

A few things make this question challenging to answer.  First, can you say what type of error page you are going to?  Is there some error text included?

Are the files you are linking to PDF files?  Word files?  Some other format?

Also, what app do you use to view the resulting PDF file.  I assume it's Acrobat's free reader, but there are many other PDF reader apps so it would be helpful to know which one you have. I think this issue is likely specific to the viewer, not the program (Word) that is converting the file.

Assuming you are using Acrobat reader, my best suggestion with the limited info provided is to follow the instructions in this article to see if your reader is configured to block links: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/allow-or-block-links-internet.html

Comment: Hi @Tamra. Thanks for the reply. I have a word file with hyperlinks to Excel sheets (each link opens a different excel sheet). These files are stored locally on my system. The idea is to distribute this pdf (with links to these excel sheet along with the actual files, so that the everybody will have the same file path. Thus the link would work (it works in word). I just want the same to happen with the pdf too. By clicking the link in the pdf a browser window opens showing the error "page not found" with could not find c:\\... path. Use word to generate pdf and free acrobat reader to open it.